# Matplotlib version 3.3.0 causes ft2font DLL ImportError

Tags: matplotlib

I recently upgraded matplotlib from version 3.2.2 to 3.3.1. When I tried to import matplotlib I got the following error message:

```py
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\SWIM\test\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "E:\SWIM\test\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

When googling for answers, most of them recommended downgrading matplotlib. But the results were many years old, and I don't feel like downgrading. I want the latest version to just work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable installed, and I didn't have any newer version. By installing the latest 2015-2019 edition, my problem was solved ([Downloads can be found here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)).